# How do I upgrade Magento 2 EE using composer

Tags: magento2.2.3, magento-enterprise-2, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2 EE using composer but I keep getting this message whenever I run `composer update/upgarde`

```
- The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.3 exists as magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.1.9] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

I have the correct keys to download the latest version using composer but would like to know what this message means so that I can resolve it?

Does anyone know what the message is referring to? Is the constraint based on a dependency in the codebase or the Magento account itself?

Edit: running `composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.3 --no-update`

I get the following response:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                                    
  Could not find a matching version of package magento/product-enterprise-edition. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which   
  matches your minimum-stability (alpha).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect you via **SSH** in the root of you Magento
2. The method is : `composer require <product> <version> --no-update`, so according to your version you have to run this:

`composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.3 --no-update`

3. ```
   rm -rf /generated
   rm -rf /var/cache/
   rm -rf /var/page_cache/

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```

More informations in [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, running the above give me an error please see edit

Comment: Are you sure that this version is available in the EE ?

Comment: According to the release notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.3EE.html

Comment: What you get with this: `yourBaseUrl/magento_version`?

Comment: I'm on version 2.1.9

Comment: Yes, but tell me exactly what you had

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for that URL

Comment: Running: php bin/magento --version Magento CLI version 2.1.9

Comment: Please, I told you to run it in the browser like this : `yourBaseUrl/magento_version` not in command line

Comment: Like I already said I get a 404 it doesn't return the version number

Comment: it's not normal to have `404` ! please try this `www.magereport.com` scan you website and give me the version

Comment: I know it's far from normal, it's a customised install things are bound to be broken.

Comment: Turns out the merchant was using the wrong keys :|